# How to sort date of different formats

Tags: java, sorting, jodatime

Below code converts a String date to a `DateTime` obj :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class SortByDate
{
    // Date format is (mm/dd/yyyy)
    private void testSort()
    {

        List<Obj> l = new ArrayList<Obj>();

        Obj o =new Obj();
        o.date = "1/5/2015 1:37:00";
        l.add(o);
        o = new Obj();
        o.date = "1/5/2015 01:38:00";
        l.add(o);
        o = new Obj();
        o.date = "1/5/2015 01:36:00";
        l.add(o);
        o = new Obj();
        o.date = "1/5/2015";
        l.add(o);


        DateTimeFormatter dtf = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        List<DateTime> dtl = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
        for(Obj ob : l){
             dtl.add(dtf.parseDateTime(ob.date));
        }

        Collections.sort(dtl);

        for(DateTime d : dtl){
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new SortByDate().testSort();
    }

    private class Obj
    {
        public String date;
    }

}
```

But I receive exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1/5/2015" is too short
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
```

To sort the date descending and cater for dates that do not have time set I plan to append "23:23:59" to Strings that have incorrect format, so `"1/5/2015"` becomes `"1/5/2015 23:23:59"`

Is there a more idiomatic approach for handling this scenario or alternative method?

Comment: I assume the offending line is the one wherein you haven't specified the time. In that case I would as an expedient append "00:00:00" (or a substring to complete the time field if partial supplied).  I'm surprised that's happening I might have to try you example. You'd think the DateTimeFormatter would assume 00:00:00 for a missing time.

Comment: Wait - Why are you using DateTime and DateTimeFormatter from  org.joda.time instead of stuff in java.util.*; package. I bet the Java stuff wouldn't throw an exception. Also it's weird that you both include the package stuff, but then specify the whole package path on the dtf definition line. There's a cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" is the format that your program expects. Passing a string with another format "MM/dd/yyyy" is properly handled as an error.

You could use regular expressions check and different dateformatter

```
 if(ob.date.matches(REG_EX_FULLDATE)){
      // use dateFormatter1
  }
 else if(ob.date.matches(REG_EX_SHORTDATE)){
     // use dateFormatter2
 } else {
       throw new RuntimeException();
 }
```